# Node Voltage Analysis with dependent voltage and current sources

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvimfU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The question for the above circuit asks for the power developed by the 60 Volt power supply. The equations I've written to solve for this value are as follows:

1. At the super node consisting of V1/V3:
   (V1-60)/100 + (V1-60)/10 + (V3-V2)/20 + V3/400 -0.625Va = 0
2. At node V2:
   (V2-60)/5 - V2/200 + (V2-V3)/20 = 0
3. KVL around the loop consisting of V1, 175Iq and V3
   V1 + 175Iq = V3

Conditional equations: 
 Va = V2-60, Iq = V2/200

The correct answer is given as 1084 watts but so far no matter how I manipulate the above equations the best I can come up with is 1057 watts and that's by making some assumptions that don't agree at all with the polarities given in the schematic. Note: when I see an arrow pointing in the direction of current through a resistor, in this case Iq through R2, I treat it as a voltage drop with the arrow pointing in the direction of the drop...it that correct? (I'm basing all my calc's on conventional current flow.)

As a final note, this is a circuit question out of the 5th edition of 'Electric Circuits' by Nilsson and Riedel. I took a course some years ago (in 1998) that used this text book so I decided I'd see how much I've forgotten since then. Apparently it's quite a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got P=1084.5 Watt. These are the equations:

1) At supernode, (V1-60)/10 + V1/100 + (V3-V2)/20 + V3/400 - 0.625Va = 0 where Va = V2 - 60

2) For supernode, V3-V1 = 175 Iq where Iq = -V2/200

3) At node V2, (V2-60)/5 + V2/200 + (V2-V3)/20 = 0

*Note: Iq flows in opposite direction of voltage drop, so the (-) sign. Also it should be V1/100 (not V1-60/100) at supernode equation.*

Solving these, V1 = -60.75, V2 = 30, V3 = -87

Total Current by 60V supply: (60-V2)/5 + (60-V1)10 = 18.075

Power = 60 * 18.075 = 1084.5 Watt

Comment: My thanks to Hassansin. My original calcs included the value 'V1/100'; just forgot to include it in the posted equation for the supernode. My error was my interpretation of sign assignments for terms associated with Iq.